# Am I allowed to lowercase an ALL CAPS section in a license?

Tags: licensing

Am I allowed to lowercase an ALL CAPS section in a license?

Example:

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2015 Andrej Karpathy
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.*

I want to lowercase the last paragraph when I redistribute it:

> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) 2015 Andrej Karpathy
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> The software is provided "as is", without warranty of any kind,
>   express or implied, including but not limited to the warranties of
>   merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and noninfringement.
>   In no event shall the authors or copyright holders be liable for any
>   claim, damages or other liability, whether in an action of contract,
>   tort or otherwise, arising from, out of or in connection with the
>   software or the use or other dealings in the software.*

Comment: This is a pretty much a dupe of this Open Source post: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/13/69 If you're asking whether you can, without making a difference, well, the answer is that you can't change it. You're actually changing the licence, and you wouldn't be allowed to call it the "MIT" licence - licences are copyrighted.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Thanks! Stack Exchange is really too fragmented :/ and I see that the question you linked to is quite similar to (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/30329/46492).

Comment: @NickT Modifying it in anyway.

Comment: @Zizouz212 what constitutes "changing" then? If I use smart-quotes instead of bi-directional quotes is it no longer the same? If I change `(c)` to `©`? If I remove the hard-linebreaks within paragraphs? What if the file is encoded with UTF-16 instead of ASCII (what is the original encoding anyways?)?

Comment: Ask a question, either here or on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). I don't want to clutter comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do *something*, if you don't like all-caps. This is a response to the requirement to be "conspicuous", as required under [UCC 2-316](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/search/display.html?terms=conspicuous&url=/ucc/2/article2.htm#s2-316), viz.

> to exclude or modify the implied warranty of merchantability or any
>   part of it the language must mention merchantability and in case of a
>   writing **must be conspicuous**, and to exclude or modify any implied
>   warranty of fitness the exclusion must be by a writing and
>   conspicuous.

YOU ARE NOT REQUIRED TO SHOUT since under [UCC 1-201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/1/1-201) "conspicuous" means

> so written, displayed, or presented that a reasonable person against
>   which it is to operate ought to have noticed it. Whether a term is
>   "conspicuous" or not is a decision for the court. Conspicuous terms
>   include the following: (A) a heading in capitals equal to or greater
>   in size than the surrounding text, or in contrasting type, font, or
>   color to the surrounding text of the same or lesser size; and (B)
>   language in the body of a record or display in larger type than the
>   surrounding text, or in contrasting type, font, or color to the
>   surrounding text of the same size, or set off from surrounding text of
>   the same size by symbols or other marks that call attention to the
>   language

There is a relevant case, [American General Finance, Inc. v. Bassett, 285 F.3d 882](https://law.resource.org/pub/us/case/reporter/F3/285/285.F3d.882.01-35058.01-35001.html), which deals with a "clear and conspicious" requirement in another context, which "sees no reason to depart" from the UCC understanding.

Comment: However, the reason why the majority of conspicuous text is ALWAYS in caps, is because it's nearly impossible to add formatting in plain text files.

Comment: Plus, traditionally, all caps was the only realistic option using a typewriter. That is why the caps-lock key was invented.

Comment: Wow, I learned something new today. Thank you! :)

Comment: The irony being that now most us probably ignore such paragraphs because we assume they say the same thing as all the others.